# Problems importing Three.js as module - getting Uncaught SyntaxError:

Tags: javascript, npm, import, module, three.js

Im learning three.js and are setting up my first project. Im basically running the example code from three.js website. It works fine when running three.js from a folder like:

> js/ directory

but I cannot get it to run when importing it as a module. 
Im installing the module with:

```
npm i three
```

And running it as a local server by installing:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

and then running my file test.html on port: 8000

```
http-server . -p 8000
```

> http://localhost:8000/test.html

Here is the full code in my body:

```
<body>
    <script>
        import * as THREE from 'three';

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
    </script>
</body>
```

How come I cannot import the module? Im getting this errormessage in the browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0):

can try

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
```

instead of import statement. 
ref: https://threejs.org

Comment: Yes that works fine indeed. But I wont to run it as a module. That is where I get the Uncaught SyntaxError